# Appium configuration - Windows

Tags: windows, installation, automation, appium

I have been trying to configure Appium on my PC referring online tutorials and guides. Though, I am unable to find a proper documentation on how the Appium setup is done and how to test an app.
Please guide me to get a proper solution.

Answer (score -1):

Appium Installation process on windows

```
1.download and install appium.exe 
2.eclipse with android config and selenium+ java 1.46 jar file with testng 6.8.5 frame work get installed
3. install additional jar file java client.jar version 2.1.0  include in your testing project.
4.in appium general setting provide server address and port number and use the same in source code.
5.write the script with help of webdriver and java code , connect appium by setting capability in source code.
6. if you are using android application debugging mode should be on while deploying to test.
7.click on appium.exe file
8. press the play button 
9.run java file as testng framework.
10.if you are running on emulator it should be open for device it should be connected to the system.
```